# Price formatting separators

Tags: formatting, currency, separator, price

I'm working on a payment product that should display prices in the currency of each relevant country. I need to display the price with the relevant thousand and decimal separators (point and comma).

In the US, dollars and cents are separated by a decimal point, and thousands are separated by a comma. However, in many countries, the opposite is true—they use commas for fractional separators and decimals for thousand separators.

Examples:

China, Chile, Columbia, Japan, USA, UK, and more - 1,234.56

Poland, Sweden, Switzerland, Vietnam, Brazil, and more - 1.234,56

Since I need to handle a lot of currencies, where can I find reliable data about each currency? And what is the best way to develop this feature? If someone has experience with this, I would love to hear how they handled it.

I found a lot of inconsistent information. I could not find a reliable source of information that gathers all the information about the separators of all currencies.
I want to find a reliable source of data that gathers all the currencies.

Answer (score 0):

Wikipedia is almost always a good start:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decimal_separator#Conventions_worldwide

Comment: Sure, but I need something more formal.
Also, I want to see how other people handled this issue.
Thanks.